# Miracast from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wifi, duplicate-display

I have a Sony Bravia R48B series TV with built-in WiFi and Miracast.

Display mirroring from my Android phone works fine.

However, I want to wirelessly mirror my laptop screen (running Windows 7) to the TV and can not find a program for it. Any suggestion of programs that can do this?

I don't want to upgrade to Windows 8.1 or buy a dongle.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be so easy. It might be that your laptop doesn't support Miracast, and if that's the case no program will be able to help you. For example, I have a 2010 laptop that first ran windows 7 and that I upgraded to Windows 8.1 Pro, and unfortunately it doesn't support Miracast. If your laptop is from around 2012 or later, it should support Miracast.

Comment: Thank you. Mine is Acer Aspire 4736 with core2Duo from 2010 . Can I use HDMI cable to output full hd screen? :)

Comment: If your laptop and TV both have HDMI, yes.

Comment: This is the second most viewed thread in this forum. Most views must be coming from nonmembers since [the first](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1308/356) has 75 upvotes while this only has 3 upvotes.

Comment: @Pacerier I'm very surprised that this simple and thousand-view question cannot have a single answer