# Git Client GUI which simplifies interface based on user's use-case

Tags: git

[This previous question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/what-is-a-good-newbie-friendly-graphical-git-client-for-windows) is almost what I want to ask, but not quite. It's also a bit old, so perhaps there's new software out there.

All the software in those answers is still relatively complex. It would be good to know if there is software which allows a user, prior to using it, to select use-cases which applies to him/her, which simplifies the GUI accordingly.

It would be awesome if it progressively narrows down the user's use-cases. starting from the most noobish.

For example:

- First it establishes if the user just wants a single local repository to save changes and record history.
- Second, it might ask if the user might want to create branches to develop a sub-module which might then be integrated into the main branch.

Etc.

Is there anything like this? Failing that, if I were to make such a client, is there any software I might base it on? Are there GIT clients which focus on very specific use-cases?